# BEM correct nesting, I dont know how to write css/less

Tags: html, css, less, classname, bem

I have big problem with BEM classing and css/less.

Here is my old html code which i want to rewrite to "BEM style":

```
<div class=header-cart">
    <ul>
        <li class="mount">
            <a href="/ncart/">
                <span />
                <span class="small_cart_price_main"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="small_cart_products">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <img />
                        <span />
                        <strong>
                            <span />
                        <strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my old css/less code structure which i want to rewrite to "BEM style" :

```
.header-cart{}
.header-cart ul{}
.header-cart li{}
.header-cart li a{}
```

This is ok, but now i need convert this old css to "BEM css/less":

```
.header-cart li.mount a{}
.header-cart li.mount .small_cart_price_main{}
.header-cart li.mount:hover > ul{}
.header-cart ul li.mount ul{}
.header-cart ul li.mount ul li a{}
.header-cart ul li.mount ul li a strong{}
```

after BEM classing(I dont know that it is ok or not :/ ):

```
<div class=header__cart">
    <ul class="header__cart-ul">
        <li class="header__cart-li header__cart-li--mount">
            <a class="header__cart-a header__cart-a--mount" href="/ncart/">
                <span />
                <span class="small_cart_price_main"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="small_cart_products">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <img />
                        <span />
                        <strong>
                            <span />
                        </strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It will look something like this:

```
.header{
&__cart{...}
&__cart-ul{...}
&__cart-li{...}
&__cart-a{...}
}
```

Problem is that i dont want my code looks like this:

For example (css style):

```
.header-cart li.mount a{}
```

(Less style):

```
.header{
    &__cart-ul .header__cart-li--mount a{
        ...
    }
}
```

or something like this:

```
.header{
    &__cart-ul{
        &__cart-li--mount{
            &__cart-a--mount{
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or even this:

```
.header-cart ul li.mount ul li a strong{}
```

Can somebody help me ?

Is there any other option how to avoid this style ? Is it correct ? Made I mistake in class naming ?

I really apologize for bad english.

Comment: Ultimately there's no real wrong way to do this. Whichever makes it easier for you and your team to read the sass selectors. I've seen BEM and 'nested' selectors really spin out of control because individuals can't actually tell how much parent selectors the selector their working with has. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So, the best way how to avoid this, is to use BEM in simple web blocks like navigation, footer etc. And in this case, just use normal HTML.

Comment: For me personally if you're already writing selectors like that there's no reason to nest the actual CSS selectors -- just style them as .header__cart-a--mount without nesting ( for ease of reading ). For all of your other components restrict yourself from styling native elements like a { } and you shouldn't have any css conflicts. Again CSS seems to be a really controversial issue so while it may be a way of doing it, it's definitely not the only way and you might find something that works better for you.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of every second question in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+bem).

Comment: Before to find a good way to write the CSS code, maybe you should learn more on BEM. Here there is a monolithic bloc `header`, with a cart that you couldn't move outside the header. Cascades like `.header-cart li` are not allowed in BEM, neither selectors with tag names.